# catkin - Suggestions for packaging isolated stacks (Orocos) with bloom?

Tags: ros, orocos, catkin, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build the [catkinized version of Orocos](https://github.com/jhu-lcsr-forks/orocos_toolchain) as a third party catkin package. However, in the first step ([FirstTimeRelease](http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/FirstTimeRelease#Creating_a_Release_Repository)) I am running into issues where bloom is searching for the dependencies in rosdep, when they are actually inside the stack, and it errors out.

Is there a way to have bloom consider packages inside this stack as the dependencies?

I have also posted an [issue on the orocos_toolchain](https://github.com/orocos-toolchain/orocos_toolchain/issues/2) project, which includes output from `bloom-release`: https://github.com/eacousineau/orocos_toolchain/blob/feature/tmp/bloom/bloom-orocos.txt#L201

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/82156/catkin---suggestions-for-packaging-isolated-stacks-(orocos)-with-bloom?/) by [eacousineau](https://answers.ros.org/users/5276/eacousineau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 174 on 2013-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you mean that you are trying to *release* the `orocos_toolchain`?

The FirstTimeRelease tutorial does not apply to third party packages. Use this tutorial instead: http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/ReleaseThirdParty

Also, there is no notion of stacks in catkin.

Also, it looks like it makes heavy use of git submodules and even pulls in the dependencies as submodules...

bloom is know to not work with submodules:

https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/issues/202

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eacousineau](https://answers.ros.org/users/5276/eacousineau/) on 2013-09-23**:
I am actually not trying to release orocos_toolchain, just seeing if I can use bloom to generate debians for internal use. The [Orocos catkin roadmap](http://www.orocos.org/wiki/main-page/development/roadmap/catkin-ros-build-support-plan) states that this is for Orocos >= v2.7.0, ROS >= Hydro, so I am just doing this on the side to see about near-term feasibility of transitioning to catkin (with ease of deployment).

Thank you for posting that issue about `git-archive`. I will look into `git-archive-all`, as well as possibly submitting a patch to `git-archive` for a `--include-submodules`` option.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At the moment the master branches of the orocos_toolchain and its submodules can easily be build with catkin_make_isolated. This means we are very close the being able to release all packages using bloom. We will do this separately for each submodule.

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Smits](https://answers.ros.org/users/350/ruben-smits/) with karma: 543 on 2013-09-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2